# Determine killer of process

Tags: python, windows-services

I got a python program running as a windows service which does in my opinion catch all exceptions. In my development environment I cannot reproduce any situation, where no exception is logged, when the program crashes. Except 2 cases: the program is killed via Task Manager or I power off the computer.

However, on the target environment (Windows 2000 with all necessary libraries and python installed), the windows service quits suddenly ca. 4 Minutes after reboots without logging any Exception or reason for the fail. The environment was definitely not powered off.

Does anybody have a suggestion how to determine what killed the python program?

**EDIT:** I cannot use a debugger in the target environment (as is it is productional level). Therefore I need a way to log the reason for the failure. So, I am looking for tools or methods to log additional information at runtime (or failure time) which can be used for post-mortem analysis.

Comment: This sounds like a stack overflow. Can you attach a debugger in the production environment?

Comment: No, unfortunately I cannot use a debugger in the target environment.

Comment: You can use "python -dv yourscript.py" to run interpreter in debug mode.
or maybe "python -m pdb yourscript.py" to run your script with the module "pdb" which is the python debugger.

Comment: Difficult as it may be, I would try to find a way to run `ntsd` in the target environment.

Comment: Use the standard strategy for production environments: write to the system log (Windows event log) at a DEBUG level of detail.

Comment: We already write to the windows event log, but there is also no information about the crash.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give more information like "Is your program multi-threaded ?" Does the code depend on the version of Python interpreter you are using, or any imported modules used not present in the target environment ?

If you have [GDB for Windows](http://hamsterrepublic.com/ohrrpgce/GDB_on_Windows.html), you can do "gdb -p pid" where "pid" is the pid of the python program you are running. If there is a crash, you can get the back trace.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check also the following tools from sysinternals.com (now acquired by MSFT):
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb795533

such as ProcDump, Process Monitor or even Process Explorer (yet less adapted than the previous ones).

You may also be able to install a lightweight debugger such as OllyDbg, or use Moonsols's tools to monitor the guest VM's process if you happen to have this in a virtualized environment.